# CRS selection for global product with minimal area distortion

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, global, distortion

I am building a model that takes data from different sites around the world as input where each pixel has a 10m resolution. I am now seeking a CRS system that works best for my use case. The requirements are that each 10mx10m pixel is close to equal in actual size anywhere in the world. This would for example really not be the case for EPSG:3857. I am considering working with UTM zones because they offer minimal distortion locally, but this would mean I would have to handle separate zones that I would ideally avoid. Additionally, I will only work at a per-pixel (or small selection) level meaning I do not require a grid that maintains correct angles to distances at a bigger scale, if there is such a property.

What do you think would meet these requirements best? I am fairly lost in this vast variety of CRSs...